# How to split multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php

I have a multi dimensional array like

```
$array = array ( [0] => array ([0] => 'stack1', [1] => 'stack2'),
                 [1] => array ([0] => 'exchange1', [1] => 'exchange2'),
         [2] => array ([0] => 'overflow1', [1] => 'overflow2'),
         [3] => array ([0] => 'super1', [1] => 'super2')
     );
```

How can i split array having specific words like 'overflow', i have to shift it to two arrays like below.
After that i want to loop.

```
$array1 = array ( [0] => array ([0] => 'stack1', [1] => 'stack2'),
                 [1] => array ([0] => 'exchange1', [1] => 'exchange2'),
          [2] => array ([0] => 'super1', [1] => 'super2')
        );

$array2 = array ( [0] => array ([0] => 'overflow1', [1] => 'overflow2') );
```

How can i achieve this using php

Comment: is there any loop less way to do it

Comment: @vvr: not really... If PHP had a function that could find partial strings in arrays, maybe, but you have to at least loop to find the matches... At least to the best of my knowledge. However, my solution shows some PHP functions that remove the need for some loops, or removes the need for additional code inside of existing loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep feeling like I'm copying Paul, second time my answer has so closely resembled his. I promise I'm not doing that on purpose. However this is different and hopefully this does the trick for you.

```
$array2 = array();
foreach( $array AS $key => $sub ) {
    foreach( $sub AS $item ) {
        if( strpos( $item, 'overflow' ) !== FALSE ) { $array2[ $key ] = ''; }
    }
}

$array2 = array_intersect_key( $array, $array2 );
$array1 = array_diff_key( $array, $array2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_find($needle, $haystack, $search_keys = false) {
    if(!is_array($haystack)) return false;
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $what = ($search_keys) ? $key : $value;
        if(strpos($what, $needle)!==false) return $key;
    }
    return false;
}

$word = 'overflow';
$c = count($array);
for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++) {
    if (array_find($word, $array[$i])) {
        $array2[] = $array[$i];
    }
    else {
        $array1[] = $array[$i];
    }
}
```

[array_find()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#95926) is similar to [array_search()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), but it also works for partial matches.

Comment: This won't work - There is never the exact work `overflow` in the array, so the `if` statement will never be evaluated. You need a more loose comparison.

Comment: I noticed that as well right after I published it, but it's fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = 'overflow'; // set the search phrase
foreach($array AS $sub) {
  $final = 1;
  foreach($sub AS $val) {
    if ( strpos($search,$val) ) { $final = 2; }
  }
  ${'array'.$final}[] = $sub;
}
```